# C# Algorithm to generate image (2048x2048) from some images

Tags: bin-packing, texture-packing

What I would like to do is create an image (2048x2048 in my case)
The algorithm should work in this way:

-User select some images from a folder and tells my program "generate image"

-The program check if can put all images inside a single image (size problem), otherwise returns an error message

-The program find the correct way to put all images inside the image and then prompt the user to choose a savepath (obviusly old images shouldn't be resized/cut)

The problem is obviusly the last step, I don't have actually idea how to do it, also there is another thing the program should check, if an image filename is myimage_1 and there is a "myimage_2" those images should be put near eachother (obiusly same for 3,4 and so on)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: That's way too much to be called an "algorithm". That's more of an application/library. By the way "spritesheet" and "texture" are two different things.

Comment: What is the correct order? What part exactly is you problem? Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: Are you trying to find the *best* way to tile sprites onto a bitmap? If so, you need a variant of a packing algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: @Camilo Martin: Mhhh if it's too big I'll avoid it, I don't want such a big thing for an "helper"

@Gabe: You are right Gabe, I would like to find the best-fit but I think is heavy... mhhh

I changed the question a bit, should be more readable without the problem of texture/spritesheet

Comment: Maybe this is kind of what you want: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Comment: So so, that it's limited by the way (0.5 MB for zip file is a problem for me)

Comment: If you download the source code and run it on your computer, you won't be affected by the upload limit.

Comment: I didn't read it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a multi-dimensional knapsack problem to me.
More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints).
There may be of course simple solutions as I'm no expert on the domain and my algorithms classes are far behind me! It will perhaps help anyway to launch the thread :)

You could perhaps also solve this by adapting an easy greedy algorithm but it will of course not give the optimal solution and will then surely lead to some false negatives for your 2nd step.

Comment: Same here, don't eat too much chocolate :) Enjoy your time with family and friends!

Comment: I already eat too much chocolate, it's a problem :P See you tomorrow I'm not able to read anything this evening

Comment: Maybe your answer is the correct one, your suggestion is ok, I'm trying to work with it and create something.

Comment: I studied a bit of what you've linked and I'm quite sure I can tag your answer as correct one, thanks for everything.